# fetch the name of model in another form in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a model named `model1` and one model have many pages. So when one create a 'model1' model, he can create pages under the model. In that creation form user have fill a form, i have to fetch the model name.

Here is the code in the `_form.php`:

```
  <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
    <h3> model1 Name: <?php echo Yii::app()->model1->name; ?></h3>
  <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
```

Where I can't get the name of the model1 name. Here how can I get the name of the model and how it fetch the name from the model.

Comment: http://code2real.blogspot.in/2015/06/yii-11-get-current-model-name.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use "**__*CLASS*__**" to get classname of the model class. Define a function inside your model class as

```
public function getName()
{
    return __CLASS__;
}
```

you can also use

```
echo $myclass = get_class($model1);
```

to get model name.